# php construct associative array key value incremental loop

Tags: php

Below is what I am trying to accomplish

```
Array
(
    [0.94] => 35
    [0.93] => 36
    [0.92] => 37
    [0.91] => 38
    .
    .
    .
    [0.50] => 79
)
```

instead of building

```
$arrayName1 = array('0.94' => '35',
                    '0.93' => '36',
                    '0.92' => '37',
                    '0.91' => '38',
                    '0.50' => '79'
                  );
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to add loop to it to simplify process. Anyone?

Comment: _"I'd like to know if there's a way to add loop to it"_ Yup, there sure is. What have you tried?

Comment: Array keys must be integer or string (not float).... if you want to use a (simulated) float key, then use a generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `range()` and `array_combine()` functions:

```
$result = array_combine(range(0.94, 0.5, -0.01), range(35, 79));
```

The `$result` contains:

```
Array
(
    [0.94] => 35
    [0.93] => 36
    [0.92] => 37
    [0.91] => 38
    [0.9] => 39
    [0.89] => 40
    [0.88] => 41
    [0.87] => 42
    [0.86] => 43
    [0.85] => 44
    [0.84] => 45
    [0.83] => 46
    [0.82] => 47
    [0.81] => 48
    [0.8] => 49
    [0.79] => 50
    [0.78] => 51
    [0.77] => 52
    [0.76] => 53
    [0.75] => 54
    [0.74] => 55
    [0.73] => 56
    [0.72] => 57
    [0.71] => 58
    [0.7] => 59
    [0.69] => 60
    [0.68] => 61
    [0.67] => 62
    [0.66] => 63
    [0.65] => 64
    [0.64] => 65
    [0.63] => 66
    [0.62] => 67
    [0.61] => 68
    [0.6] => 69
    [0.59] => 70
    [0.58] => 71
    [0.57] => 72
    [0.56] => 73
    [0.55] => 74
    [0.54] => 75
    [0.53] => 76
    [0.52] => 77
    [0.51] => 78
    [0.5] => 79
)
```

Comment: OP's numbers are off.  Those numbers give arrays of different length and an error.  Key array is one element longer. Should probably end at `.5` or value end at `80`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I can't figure what you mean with *numbers are off*

Comment: @AbraCadaver, that's really annoying PHP behaviour

Comment: Yes, seems that PHP 7 only went to `.5` even though you used `0.49`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, It seems to work till PHP `7.0.2`, with all further/newer version - throws warning

Comment: The funny thing is that PHP7 is only of for 0.94 to 0.97; 0.98 works again: https://3v4l.org/ESFND.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Awesome that is really elegant solution! I get array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements so fixing range 0.49 to 0.5 fix the problem =)

Comment: @AbraCadaver, you know what I think? No one should use php's `range()` for currency/money calculations, it's really disappointing

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop.

```
$data = array();
$i = 0.94;
$j = 35;
while($i > 0.50){
    $data[(string)$i] = $j;
    $i -= 0.01;
    $j++;
}

var_dump($data);
```